# Python ImportError : undefined symbol: openblas_get_num_threads

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

**Does anyone know how to fix the Python importError?**

Let me explain you what I am trying to do and what I did to get this error.

I'm trying to load a video using OpenCV3 with python3 in my Debian environment but I installed a version using conda that did not have the FFmpeg option enabled, so it can`t load .mp4 videos.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/sf_winsharefolder/pooljob/addingball.mp4'); 
print(cap.isOpened())
while(cap.isOpened()):
    print('isopen')
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
    #gray =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I did was unistall the OpenCV version that I had and then install a version using conda from this [link](https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock/issues/43#issuecomment-268855767)

```
conda install -c loopbio -c conda-forge -c pkgw-forge ffmpeg-feature ffmpeg gtk2 opencv.
```

When I tried to import OpenCV with the command

```
import cv2
```

It threw an exception:

```
then an error : libopenblas.so.0 cannot open shared object file no such file or directory
```

After that I fixed the error following the instructions from this [link](https://github.com/sermanet/OverFeat/issues/10):

The fix is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base
```

And then

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/openblas-base/
```

But now is thrwing a new error:

> ImportError:
>   /home/tensor/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow35Opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/../../libopencv_dnn.so.3.2:
>   undefined symbol: openblas_get_num_threads

Comment: Same problem here. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.5.